# EXCEL countif statement when specific rows are selected?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have the following formulas which work separately but how do I combine them.
I would like to count all cells with a "D" & "N" between columns B & AJ but only for rows that contain worker1

Count rows with worker1
=COUNTIFS(A2:A100, "worker1")

count all shifts between column B & AJ
=SUM(COUNTIF(B:AJ,{"D","N"}))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B4:AJ100="D")+(B4:AJ100="n"))*(A4:A100="worker1"))
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, that is perfect.